# Check if JS plugin is loaded before executing code

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, plugins, ecmascript-5

I'd like some insight into a little problem I'm encountering with a custom JS plugin that I've made. It's reasonably simple, I'm using a plugin JS template to write out plugins, which I'll attach. I'm then initialising the plugin, and ideally need to figure out if there's a way I can check if the plugin JS file is loaded before doing anything:

**plugin template**

```js
(function() {
  this.MyPlugin = function() {

    // default settings
    const INBOUND_CONFIG = {
      isEnabled: false
    }

    // Create options by extending defaults with the passed in arugments
    if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
      this.options = extendDefaults(INBOUND_CONFIG, arguments[0]);
    }

    // custom public method
    HoneycombInbound.prototype.getSettings = function() {

    }

    // Utility method to extend defaults with user options
    function extendDefaults(source, properties) {
      var property;
      for (property in properties) {
        if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          source[property] = properties[property];
        }
      }
      return source;
    }

  }
}());
```

With the above, I'd initialise the plugin in HTML as follows:

```html
<script src="./my-plugin.js"></script>

<script>
  const plugin = new MyPlugin()

  // this doesn't work if the script file isn't linked:
  if (plugin) {
    // do something
  }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, a simple check of `plugin` doesn't actually work if the JS file isn't loaded for instance, I've even tried something like: `if (new MyPlugin()) {}` with little hope.

I essentially need a way of **not throwing an error in the browser. Any solution I can use to check correctly if it's loaded before executing?**

Answer (score 0):

A solution that has worked for me is to work with the `WebAPI` [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

I've used to communicate with the client, that the plugin is ready.

So on the **plugin** you will need something like this:

`window.postMessage("The plugin is ready to go" );`

And on your **client** you will need to add a new listener that can catch the message:

```
window.addEventListener("message", myMessage, false);

const myMessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data === "The plugin is ready to go")
  // This is your message so do your stuff here
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**

So to achieve this behavio, you will need to enable on the client sidethe initialization:

```
const myPlugin = {
  init: () => { 
    // Initilize the plugin if you are using the DOM you can add a parameter with an id to mount it whenever you need it
    //Otherwise just configure or initilize the variables that you will use 
    // And here you need to pass the messsage to tell the client that everyting is ready
    // Here you need to configure the origin correctly depending on your needs check the documentation for more details 
    window.addEventListener("message", myMessage, false);
  },
  someFunctionality: () => {
    //This pattern is to expose the funtionalities to the client so you can achieve any
  }
};
```

So now on your client you just need to add your script and tell the plugin to initialize:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/myPlugin.js'></script>
<script>
 window.addEventListener("message", myMessage, false);

 const myMessage = (event) => {
   if (event.data === "The plugin is ready to go")
   // This is your message so do your stuff here
   ...
 }
 myPlugin.init();

</script>
```

Comment: Great but I still have to initialise the plugin with `const plugin = new MyPlugin()` and if the JS file isn't loaded, `new MyPlugin()` is undefined regardless of the event listener?

Comment: I just updated the answer to be more clear on the pattern that has worked for me